# How to prohibit the pulldown ListView effect?

Tags: android, listview

I create a common Android spinner effect like this:

[image]

It looks like has different effect in different Manufacturers machine.

When press on the top of view and drag down, it can pull in some machine. But it can not pull in other machine.

Is it created well when making the machine?

I want to prohibit the pulldown `ListView` effect. How to do it? Is it could to use scrollview?

Answer (score 0):

Does this have any effect?

```
setOverScrollMode(View.OVER_SCROLL_NEVER)
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#setOverScrollMode(int)
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#OVER_SCROLL_NEVER